# A couple of questions about password policies for Android devices

Tags: android, device-admin, password-policy

The application is device administrator, it can set a password policy with expiration time for the password.

1. How will the user be notified about the expired password? Does it depend on the application? Or it will be standard android behavior?
2. Can I trick the app by changing the device time forward (to enforce the expiration)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How will the user be notified about the expired password? Does it depend on the application? Or it will be standard android behavior?

It will be standard *device* behavior, but that behavior may be altered by device manufacturers or ROM mod authors.

> Can I trick the app by changing the device time forward (to enforce the expiration)?

Since I am not aware that a non-root Android app can change the system time, I would assume the answer here is "no".